# Meractor projection for converting longititude and lattitude to x and y coordinates

Tags: java, mercator

I have been looking for the conversion of longitude and lattitude and found this algorith which i am currently using and not sure if this is the right algorithm. Also how do i paint the specific coordinates on the map picture with using the tooltip. I tried overriding the paintComponent method inside JPanel but i need the tag picture to be a label so i can use the JTooltip properly. Below is the algorithm i am curently using. Please let me know if its right and also how to place another picture on the top of the main picture. as with using the JLabel i used the setBounds method to set the location but dosent work properly given a list of points to place.

public Point getXY(Double longitude, Double latitude) {

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    double mapWidth = 2000; 
    double mapHeight = 1000;
    // get x value
    double x = (longitude + 180) * (mapWidth / 360);
    int x1 = (int) Math.round(x);
    list.add(x1);
    // convert from degrees to radians
    double latRad = latitude * Math.PI / 180;

    // get y value
    double mercN = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + (latRad / 2)));
    double y = (mapHeight / 2) - (mapWidth * mercN / (2 * Math.PI));
    int y1 = (int) Math.round(y);
    list.add(y1);
    return new Point(x1, y1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you have the equations, the implementation is straight forward. However, for operations like this it is good to use Geotools, an opensource java library which provides GIS functionalities like that. Here is a tutorial showing how you can transform between different coordinate reference systems: [geotools CRS tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/geometry/geometrycrs.html) 
Here is a tutorial which showes you how to deal with image and CRS-coordinates:

[Geotools Affine transformation](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/affinetransform.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any conversion from lat/long to XY is called a "projection", and there are a lot of different ones. There is no "right" projection because any mapping from a sphere or ellipsoid (the Earth is slightly flattened rather than a perfect sphere) to a flat plane is going to involve some distortion.

You don't say what projection you are using here. You should, even if its just a basic one, so that anyone reading the code in the future knows where you got your equations from and can check them for correctness. Also, we can't tell you whether you have got it right without some notion of what "right" would mean in this case.

Have you tried some test data? If you know roughly what results you expect, for instance if you have a paper map that uses the same projection, then you can verify your algorithm by putting in the lat-long for a specific landmark and checking if the XY result matches the map position. There are also some web sites that can provide accurate conversions for specific projections if that is what you need.

The right projection very much depends on what you want to do. It sounds like you just want a recognizable rendering of a small geographic area (such as a US state or European country). If so then pretty much any projection will do.

If you want something accurate, so you can measure distances or angles on a map or do navigation within a mile over long distances, then life gets complicated very fast, and if you can use a pre-existing library then its a very good idea. But I don't think thats what you need here.